Understanding Python Asynchronous Programming
Here is a segment of Python asynchronous programming code.

async def my_task(task_id):
    print(f"Task {task_id} started, waiting for 2 seconds...")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)  
    print(f"Task {task_id} finished.")


async def main():
    tasks = [my_task(i) for i in range(3)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  


asyncio.run(main())

When all three my_task tasks are in the sleep state, from the perspective of the operating system, is the Python thread in a ready state, a blocked state, or a running state?
If the Python thread is switching between the ready state and the running state, does that mean the Python thread is constantly polling whether these 3 tasks have finished waiting? If that’s the case, wouldn’t it waste CPU resources? Or is there some mechanism that addresses this issue?
I want to know which concepts I should understand in order to grasp the principles of asynchronous programming.


When all three my_task tasks are in the sleep state, from the
perspective of the operating system, is the Python thread in a ready
state, a blocked state, or a running state?

It is blocked in a select(or poll, epoll, etc depending on the operating system)(link to the source code) call with a timeout which is calculated based on scheduled tasks or if it has other tasks to do it's gonna execute them.

does that mean the Python thread is constantly polling whether these 3
tasks have finished waiting?

No.
It waits for an event from the operating system(again that select call) this means there is no hot loop in python to check for readiness of the tasks.
